# Jumps in GPS location during region monitoring

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, region-monitoring

I have region monitoring feature in my iOS application. I have certain locations marked as projects and when a user reaches to any of that location, GPS triggeres the Enter and Exit project events. But somtimes it works weirdly for Exit location event. Following are some observations.

1. For most of the regions, the radius is ~200 meters. But `didExitLocation` triggers a random location around 500 to 700 meters away from the region. The location object receieved in that call has speed -1 and accuracy around 30 to 200 meters.
2. After few seconds of this exit event, region motoring triggers `didEnterLocation` and `locationDeterminedInside` methods again. In actual, user was inside that region only and did not move to that location. It was a jump in the location.

My question is, How can I deal with such jumps in the best way?

I have tried to monitor location speed and avoid exit calls that have speed = -1. But it is not consistent always. Sometimes speed is -1 even when user actually leave the region.

Comment: It depends on the application. Sometime the phone tell you about bad accuracy (as you wrote *200m* (which in reality can be much much more: it was accuracy of last fix, maybe 5 minutes ago). Check accuracy and stability (if you remain in the location for more than 5 fixes, you can assume you are there. Check also delay expectation of user (by foot, car?). And try to find good parameters (accuracy, delay time) for your application. Speed is calculated independently.